# Incrementing a counter in DynamoDB when value to be updated is in a map field

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto

I have a lambda function that needs to retrieve an item from DynamoDB and update the counter of that item. But..

The DynamoDB table is structured as:

```
id: int
options: map
    some_option: 0
    some_other_option: 0
```

I need to first retrieve the item of the table that has a certain `id` and a certain option listed as a key in the `options`.

Then I want to increment that counter by some `value`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('options')

response = None
try:
    response = table.get_item(Key={'id': id})
except ClientError as e:
    print(e.response['Error']['Message'])

option = response.get('Item', None)
if option:
    option['options'][some_option] = int(option['options'][some_option]) + some_value
    # how to update item in DynamoDB now?
```

My issues is how to update the record now and more importantly **will such solution cause data races**? Could 2 simultaneous lambda calls that try to update the same item at the same option cause data races? If so what's the way to solve this?

Any pointers/help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer:

All I need is:

```
response = table.update_item(
    Key={
        'id': my_id,
    }, 
    UpdateExpression='SET options.#s = options.#s + :val',  
    ExpressionAttributeNames={
        "#s": my_option
    },  
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ':val': Decimal(some_value)
    },
    ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
)
```

This is inspired from [Step 3.4: Increment an Atomic Counter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Python.03.html#GettingStarted.Python.03.04) which provides an atomic approach to increment values. According to the documentation:

> DynamoDB supports atomic counters, which use the update_item method to
> increment or decrement the value of an existing attribute without
> interfering with other write requests. (All write requests are applied
> in the order in which they are received.)